# How to create interface based on function parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to sort of dynamically create an instance of an interface that has a key that is specified dynamically, through a function parameter

effectively I want to do something simple like this:

```
function callWith(key, value) {
   return fnWithKeyValue => 
     fnWithKeyValue({ [key]: value });
}
```

(What I specifically want this for is a React HOC with the ability to set a dynamic property, but I've tried to simplify above)

For instance, lets say I there is some function more or less beyond my control:

```
interface ValueType {
  magicValue: number;
}

function MyCallback(v: ValueType) {

}
```

And so I want this to successfully compile:

```
callWith('magicValue', 123)(MyCallback);
```

but I want this to fail to compile:

```
callWith('normalValue', 123)(MyCallback);
```

Is this even possible with TypeScript?

Comment: Why not just pass the object directly to `MyCallback` and do the check inside it?

Comment: This example maybe simplifies it too much - I'm trying to generalize this so that it accepts any MyCallback as a parameter, and I want the type signatures to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function callWith<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): <R>(f: (a: Record<K, V>) => R) => R {
   return fnWithKeyValue => 
     fnWithKeyValue({ [key]: value } as Record<K, V>); // Note the cast here, I don't know of a way to avoid it.
}
```

It's a little tricky, since we've got a generic function `callWith`, that returns yet another generic function. But all it says is that the function you give as an argument to the function returned by `callWith` must accept the right type of object as it's parameter, specifically a `Record<K, V>`.

But, despite it's complex signature, it does seem to meet your requirements. The first example will compile without issue, but the second will create an error since `MyCallback` accepts an object with `"magicValue"` and not `"normalValue"`:

```
interface ValueType {
  magicValue: number;
}

function MyCallback(v: ValueType) {}

callWith('magicValue', 123)(MyCallback); // OK
callWith('normalValue', 123)(MyCallback); // Error: Property 'magicValue' is missing in type 'Record<"normalValue", number>'
```